# How can I build a hierarchy tree from flat data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a json data like this :

```
Data = [{"Id":"1", "Name":"abc", "Parent":""}, {"Id":"2", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"1"},
{"Id":"3", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"},{"Id":"4", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"}]
```

I want to transform this data into hierarchy tree like this :

```
root: {
        Id:"1",
        Name:"abc", 
        Parent:"",
        0: {
            Id:"2",
            Name:"abc",
            Parent:"1",
             0:{
                Id:"3",
                Name:"abc",
                Parent:"2",
             1:{
                Id:"4",
                Name:"adb",
                Parent:"2",
.....
}
```

Currently I have the idea only make it as the array object but that format won't work for me. Because I need this format for TreeTable in sapui5.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON example does not make sense completely, as you generally would have some array to hold the child nodes. But here's an example that should be easy to adapt to different structures. There is room for optimization, and some of the loops could be combined together for slightly more efficient code. I broke all the things to different loops to make the code more understandable. For sure there are other approaches, but this is one:

```
var data = [{"Id":"1", "Name":"abc", "Parent":""}, {"Id":"2", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"1"}, {"Id":"3", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"},{"Id":"4", "Name":"abc", "Parent":"2"}];

// flatten to object with string keys that can be easily referenced later
var flat = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var key = 'id' + data[i].Id;
  flat[key] = data[i];
}

// add child container array to each node
for (var i in flat) {
  flat[i].children = []; // add children container
}

// populate the child container arrays
for (var i in flat) {
  var parentkey = 'id' + flat[i].Parent;
  if (flat[parentkey]) {
    flat[parentkey].children.push(flat[i]);
  }
}

// find the root nodes (no parent found) and create the hierarchy tree from them
var root = [];
for (var i in flat) {
  var parentkey = 'id' + flat[i].Parent;
  if (!flat[parentkey]) {
      root.push(flat[i]);
  }
}

// here it is!
window.console.log(root);
```

Comment: If you remove that `'id'+` from every key it will make even more concise code

Comment: The `'id'+` was added to avoid any confusion / accidental type conversion to numeric indexes. As in the source format the id and parent values look like numbers, but are technically strings. But it's probably not exactly necessary.

Comment: is there a general way to do this? are there any standard methode where I can pass parent and child - ID or do I really have to do this by coding like yaku did?

Comment: Keep in mind that the above answer uses four loops, and hence could be improved. Since I could not find a npm module which implements a O(n) solution, I created the following one (unit tested, 100% code coverage, only 0.5 kb in size and includes typings. Maybe it helps someone: npmjs.com/package/performant-array-to-tree