# SAPUI5 create JSON for TreeTable / empty rows

Tags: javascript, json, data-binding, sapui5, treetable

I want to create a SAPUI TreeTable from a JSON request, currently my output looks like this (as you can see, every node contains an empty row -> I do not know where this is coming from and I do not want to have these empty rows):

[image: emptyRows]

My Table definition:

```
//Create an instance of the table control
var oTreeTable = new sap.ui.table.TreeTable({
    columns: [
        new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                text : "",
            }),
            template : 
                new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                text : "{Title}",
                textAlign : sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Begin,
            }),     
        }),
        //new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "Mon01", template: "Mon01"}),
        //new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "Mon02", template: "Mon02"}),
        //new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "Mon03", template: "Mon03"}),
        //new sap.ui.table.Column({label: "Mon04", template: "Mon04"}),
    ],
    selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.None,
    enableColumnReordering: false,
    expandFirstLevel: false,
    toggleOpenState: function(oEvent) {

    }
});
```

My getJSON and convert flat structure to parent/child structure (thanks to [yaku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553072/how-can-i-build-a-hierarchy-tree-from-flat-data-in-javascript/16553735#comment40559972_16553735))

```
    $.getJSON(sServiceUrl, function (data) {

        // flatten to object with string keys that can be easily referenced later
        var flat = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
          var key = 'id' + data.d.results[i].ID;
          flat[key] = data.d.results[i];
        }

        // add child container array to each node
        for (var i in flat) {
          flat[i].children = []; // add children container
        }

        // populate the child container arrays
        for (var i in flat) {
          var parentkey = 'id' + flat[i].ParentId;
          if (flat[parentkey]) {
            flat[parentkey].children.push(flat[i]);
          }
        }

        // find the root nodes (no parent found) and create the hierarchy tree from them
        var root = [];
        for (var i in flat) {
          var parentkey = 'id' + flat[i].ParentId;
          if (!flat[parentkey]) {
              root.push(flat[i]);
          }
        }

        // here it is!          
        // console.log(root);    

        // to access the JSON via "/root" in bindRows(), could this be a problem?? 
        var data = {
                root  :  root,  
        };

        console.log(data);

        var oTreeModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oTreeModel.setData(data);
        oTreeTable.setModel(oTreeModel);
        oTreeTable.bindRows({
            path : '/root',
        });
```

My Result JSON (a part of it): where I can not find why there are empty rows shown ?? Anybody knows something?

[image: JSON object]

Thanks!

Edit: this is my complete JSON result (var root) (BEFORE I move it to var data = { root  :  root, }; which is bound to the tree table via bindRows(/root).. )

```
{
  "d" : {
    "results" : [
      {
        "__metadata" : {
          "id" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000001')",
          "uri" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000001')",
          "type" : " NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
        },
        "Mon04" : "",
        "Mon03" : "",
        "Mon02" : "09/2014",
        "Mon01" : "08/2014",
        "Title" : "Parent 1",
        "ID" : "00000001",
        "ParentId" : "",
        "ChildId" : "",
      },
      {
        "__metadata" : {
          "id" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000002')",
          "uri" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000002')",
          "type" : "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
        },
        "Mon04" : "",
        "Mon03" : "",
        "Mon02" : "1560",
        "Mon01" : "1550",
        "Title" : "Parent 2",
        "ID" : "00000002",
        "ParentId" : "",
        "ChildId" : "",
      },
      {
        "__metadata" : {
          "id" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000003')",
          "uri" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000003')",
          "type" : "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
        },
        "Mon04" : "",
        "Mon03" : "",
        "Mon02" : "1860",
        "Mon01" : "1750",
        "Title" : "Child 1",
        "ID" : "00000003",
        "ParentId" : "00000002",
        "ChildId" : "00000001",
      },
      {
        "__metadata" : {
          "id" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000004')",
          "uri" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000004')",
          "type" : "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
        },
        "Mon04" : "",
        "Mon03" : "",
        "Mon02" : "1860",
        "Mon01" : "1750",
        "Title" : "Child 1_1",
        "ID" : "00000004",
        "ParentId" : "00000003",
        "ChildId" : "00000001",
      },
      {
        "__metadata" : {
          "id" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000005')",
          "uri" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000005')",
          "type" : "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
        },
        "Mon04" : "",
        "Mon03" : "",
        "Mon02" : "2060",
        "Mon01" : "1950",
        "Title" : "Child 2",
        "ID" : "00000005",
        "ParentId" : "00000002",
        "ChildId" : "00000001",
      },
      {
        "__metadata" : {
          "id" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000006')",
          "uri" : "http://url/EntitySet('00000006')",
          "type" : "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
        },
        "Mon04" : "",
        "Mon03" : "",
        "Mon02" : "2060",
        "Mon01" : "1950",
        "Title" : "Child 3",
        "ID" : "00000006",
        "ParentId" : "00000002",
        "ChildId" : "00000001",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

During trying to remove the bullet points I found that they are included in HTML, but I dont know why. If I remove this  via dev-tools, the bullet point is gone...

[image: bullet points]

which comes from CSS icon class...

.sapUiTableTreeIconLeaf {
 background-image: url(ico12_leaf.gif);
}

solved it via

.sapUiTableTreeIconLeaf {
    background-image: none !important;
}

Comment: Hi, could you please give an example of your result JSON string?

Comment: added it, I hope this is what you expected (sorry I changed it a little bit to that what you see from picture, added a sub-sub-child) but I think you want to see the structure. Thanks Allen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just get rid of the __metadata, set `flat[key].__metadata = ""` , i guess TreeTable renderer must take it for another child.

```
// flatten to object with string keys that can be easily referenced later
var flat = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
    var key = 'id' + data.d.results[i].ID;
    flat[key] = data.d.results[i];
    flat[key].__metadata = "";
}
```

### Updated Code Snippet:

```js
    
    sap.ui.jsview("test.view", {
        getControllerName: function() {
            return "test.controller";
        },
        createContent: function(oController) {
            var oTreeTable = new sap.ui.table.TreeTable({
                columns: [
                    new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label: "Title",
                        template: "Title"
                    }),
                    new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label: "Mon01",
                        template: "Mon01"
                    }),
                    new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label: "Mon02",
                        template: "Mon02"
                    }),
                    new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label: "Mon03",
                        template: "Mon03"
                    }),
                    new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label: "Mon04",
                        template: "Mon04"
                    }),
                ],
                selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.None,
                enableColumnReordering: false,
                expandFirstLevel: false,
                toggleOpenState: function(oEvent) {

                }
            });

            var data = {
                "d": {
                    "results": [{
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "http://url/EntitySet('00000001')",
                            "uri": "http://url/EntitySet('00000001')",
                            "type": " NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
                        },
                        "Mon04": "",
                        "Mon03": "",
                        "Mon02": "09/2014",
                        "Mon01": "08/2014",
                        "Title": "Parent 1",
                        "ID": "00000001",
                        "ParentId": "",
                        "ChildId": "",
                    }, {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "http://url/EntitySet('00000002')",
                            "uri": "http://url/EntitySet('00000002')",
                            "type": "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
                        },
                        "Mon04": "",
                        "Mon03": "",
                        "Mon02": "1560",
                        "Mon01": "1550",
                        "Title": "Parent 2",
                        "ID": "00000002",
                        "ParentId": "",
                        "ChildId": "",
                    }, {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "http://url/EntitySet('00000003')",
                            "uri": "http://url/EntitySet('00000003')",
                            "type": "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
                        },
                        "Mon04": "",
                        "Mon03": "",
                        "Mon02": "1860",
                        "Mon01": "1750",
                        "Title": "Child 1",
                        "ID": "00000003",
                        "ParentId": "00000002",
                        "ChildId": "00000001",
                    }, {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "http://url/EntitySet('00000004')",
                            "uri": "http://url/EntitySet('00000004')",
                            "type": "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
                        },
                        "Mon04": "",
                        "Mon03": "",
                        "Mon02": "1860",
                        "Mon01": "1750",
                        "Title": "Child 1_1",
                        "ID": "00000004",
                        "ParentId": "00000003",
                        "ChildId": "00000001",
                    }, {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "http://url/EntitySet('00000005')",
                            "uri": "http://url/EntitySet('00000005')",
                            "type": "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
                        },
                        "Mon04": "",
                        "Mon03": "",
                        "Mon02": "2060",
                        "Mon01": "1950",
                        "Title": "Child 2",
                        "ID": "00000005",
                        "ParentId": "00000002",
                        "ChildId": "00000001",
                    }, {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "http://url/EntitySet('00000006')",
                            "uri": "http://url/EntitySet('00000006')",
                            "type": "NAMESPACE_SRV.Entity"
                        },
                        "Mon04": "",
                        "Mon03": "",
                        "Mon02": "2060",
                        "Mon01": "1950",
                        "Title": "Child 3",
                        "ID": "00000006",
                        "ParentId": "00000002",
                        "ChildId": "00000001",
                    }]
                }
            };

            var flat = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                var key = 'id' + data.d.results[i].ID;
                flat[key] = data.d.results[i];
                flat[key].__metadata = "";
            }

            // add child container array to each node
            for (var i in flat) {
                flat[i].children = []; // add children container
            }

            // populate the child container arrays
            for (var i in flat) {
                var parentkey = 'id' + flat[i].ParentId;
                if (flat[parentkey]) {
                    flat[parentkey].children.push(flat[i]);
                }
            }

            // find the root nodes (no parent found) and create the hierarchy tree from them
            var root = [];
            for (var i in flat) {
                var parentkey = 'id' + flat[i].ParentId;
                if (!flat[parentkey]) {
                    root.push(flat[i]);
                }
            }

            // here it is!          
            // console.log(root);    

            // to access the JSON via "/root" in bindRows(), could this be a problem?? 
            var data = {
                root: root,
            };

            console.log(data);

            var oTreeModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oTreeModel.setData(data);
            oTreeTable.setModel(oTreeModel);
            oTreeTable.bindRows({
                path: '/root',
            });



            return oTreeTable;
        },
    });

    sap.ui.controller("test.controller", {
        onInit: function() {

        }
    });

    sap.ui.view({
            type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
            viewName: "test.view"
        })
        .placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.viz" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"></script>  
<body class="sapUiBody">
  <div id="uiArea"></div> 
</body>
```

Comment: wow. okay... how did you get there? it would be very kind if you let me know how to tackle such a problem, did you debug it? if yes how? thanks allen, once more!!

Comment: hi zyrex, i didn't debug it. I firstly check the sample data from yaku, the tree table renders the data correctly, thus it occurred to me there must be something wrong with your data, so i asked the example of your data, the _metadata object existed in your data, so i deleted the object and gave it a try, it worked. I will try to find the root cause of why UI5 tree table has this behavior later.

Comment: one last thing, I still got some kind of bullet point in front of each child-row (each row which is not expandable has a bullet point at the beginning, which is in the example of yaku not the case), is there anything else I should clear before binding? thank you !

Comment: hi zyrex, i just added the code snippet, it works for me, no bullet point at the beginning. Please check.

Comment: hi allen, I dont know whats wrong, but still in my case it shows those bullet points. Im reworking the json during getJSON, could this be a problem? Currently I dont see any difference in the code... except that I have to access my data via "{Title}", and you can access via "Title" ... hmm

Comment: Hi zyrex, so it worked before you refactored your code? Do you mind that i take a look at your new code if possible  to get this strange issue?

Comment: no :( first I had the thing with metadata, now the tree works, but the bullet points are shown at every node which has children.length = 0 ... Ill add another example, thanks!

Comment: so, I've updated, the only difference I see right now is that I use textfields as template in the table. from processing: I create the table, then catch data via getJSON (inside this call I bind the rows) ... thats pretty it, quite exactly as shown in my post. it seems that I got the bullet points right from the beginnen, first with empty rows, now at every non-exandable row... Ill add an picture with html code, I found that this bullet point seems explicitly being included in my HTML ..

Comment: Hi zyrex, i cannot reproduce your issue unfortunately. which browser are you using?

Comment: I also do not know where this is coming from, can you help me how to remove the <span>-elements via jquery? I think removing every span with title="Knoten" (whereever this comes from) has to be removed... or should I better go via the css? overriding the background image? I think this would be smoother, but putting background-image to none does not make a change in css class sapUiTableTreeIconLeaf

Comment: This kind of workaround is not best option. Is it possible you can build a simple case which produces your issue in JSBin so i can take a look into?

Comment: I know, but I cannot reproduce it, so I changed css class to background-image: none !important; which works for me ;-)