# Why is sap.ui.table.TreeTable showing phantom rows (improper data rendering)?

Tags: sapui5, treetable

I have posted a reconstruction of the problem here http://jsbin.com/pakututana/1/edit.

The data should lead to a rendering of a 2-level depth nodes in the TreeTable. But instead there a phantom rows cluttering the it.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Saw the link you posted. The `JSON` you created is not the valid for the `TreeTable` Let me point out some of the mistakes you did in your code.

**Check the points:**

```
1. var tData = {"SessionTransactions":{}} //This is not required its unnecessarily declared  

     //   Use this directly
    var tData = { 
            "":{},
            "SessionTransactions":{//Some Value}
     };

2. tData = {
        "": {},
        "SessionTransactions": {
            0: {
                0: {},
                1: {},
                2: {},
                3: {},
                4 :{   //This was missing which leads to the empty row
                   "__metadata": {},
                   "Service": {},
                   "Poi": {}
                }
            },
            1: {
              0:{}
            }
          }
    };
3. The second level child with empty rows is because of "__metadata","Service" and "Poi"
      0:{
        "__metadata": {},
        "Service": {},
        "Poi": {}
      }
```

Try now after changing the json. I think it may help you

Comment: if the solution solved your query you can accept the answer(by selecting the green tick mark), or else if you have something else you can ask that too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the search next time, you have to clear .__metadata = ""; - property...

[SAPUI5 create JSON for TreeTable / empty rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927797/sapui5-create-json-for-treetable-empty-rows)